# Automatically import files to carousel gallery using javascript and "for" loop to populate the matrix

Tags: javascript, for-loop, matrix, filenames

**I am trying to create a carousel gallery that will only show the 5 most recent photos from an folder, while keeping many photos in the folder for people to browse through a different link.**

---

The examples I have seen online all use full urls for each image in the matrix, which would require me going into the code every week and changing it.
I plan to upload the photos into the folder myself, and name them by date (yyyymmdd) so that the newest will always be first, but do not know how to make a javascript function call the items out.

I have a rough idea for how to insert the fileName (variable?) into the img src"" tag, it is just the getting the fileName
I think it should be similar to the following code, but am new to JS so have not been able to find the answer myself...

```
var i,c;
let i = "//dateinformat=yymmdd//";

for (let c = 0; c++){
    for (let i=//dateinformat=yymmdd//; i--{
        if["/images/" i ".jpeg"] = ""(
        i--;
        else (let fileName=[ "/images/" i ".jpeg"]);
    }
}
```

If anyone can suggest a website that shows me the solution, or provide the correct coding, then I will be grateful.

I am using Visual Studio Code with a live server, for now, on a HP laptop running chrome web-browser.
I am, also, currently running the script in the html while I try to get it working.

--

I have tried playing with the code and using a javascript "fetch" query every time, but couldn't get my head around that either.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the browser or are you using Node?

Comment: @jme11Live Server (browser) on laptop before I upload and make the page live.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this from the browser using [XMLHttpRequest (XHR)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/XMLHttpRequest)

Here's how to make this work:

1. Create a folder named `images` that is in the root of your project and add some random images to it.
2. Create an index.html.
3. Add the JS below with a script tag.
4. Add an element with an id of `img-container` (i.e., `<div id="img-container"></div>`) to the page.

The code is heavily commented so you can modify to your needs.

```js
const imgEl = document.createElement('img');
const imgContainer = document.getElementById('img-container');

// create a new request object
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// set the method to get and the url to
// the folder containing your images
// the third property is whether to make the
// request asynchronously so it's non-blocking
xhr.open('GET', './images', true);
// this response type document means that
// we're going to get back a document describing
// the contents of the folder which will
// allow us to query that document to get all of
// the image urls.
xhr.responseType = 'document';
// the onload event is where we'll add the callback
// to dictate what happens when the request is
// fulfilled
xhr.onload = () => {
  // check if the response was OK
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // query the document we get back to find all
    // the anchor tags
    const elements = xhr.response.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // loop over the anchor tags
    for (element of elements) {
      // the tags will include anchor tags for the directory,
      // subdirectories and files, so we only want the ones
      // that are images.
      if (element.href.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
        // create an img tag
        const img = imgEl.cloneNode();
        // set its src to the href of the anchor tag
        img.src = element.href;
        // append it to the image container element
        imgContainer.appendChild(img);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // if the request fails, we'll log the error in the console
    // for debugging purposes
    console.error('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
  }
};
// send the request!
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This works at pulling the contents of the folder in, which helps with a side-project I had thought about.
Do you know how to make this run only a set amount of times, though?
I have tried enclosing it in for/while loops or putting loops inside but all this does is duplicate the data returned. I am struggling to get it to, for example, only provide the first 5 matching documents.